# python twilio HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.twilio.com', port=443) Max retries exceeded with url

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, python-requests, twilio

```
sid = "*****************************"
token = "*****************************"
client = Client(sid, token)
message = client.messages.create(to="+91**********", from_="+12********", body="Hello from twilio")
```

while running above snippet I am getting the error:

> ssl.SSLError: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol

I am running it using virtual environment of python3.4. 
I am not sure what is going wrong here.

Comment: Is there any more to the code? Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Nope. I am running the code from virtulbox hosting ubuntu.

Comment: What version of VirtualBox is it?

Comment: It's Oracle Virtualbox 5.1.16 hosting ubuntu 14.04.5

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I am not entirely sure here, but I think your TLS support may be out of date. I'm using an answer rather than a comment as this takes more space.

Can you try running the following python program from your ubuntu vm and report the result:

```
import requests;
print(requests.get('https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check', verify=False).json()['tls_version']);
```

**Edit**

Ok, that's not the problem, although you are able to make a request which is something. Can you do the same with `requests` and a Twilio endpoint? Something like:

```
import requests;
request = requests.get('https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID/Messages.json', auth=('YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID', 'YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN'));
print request.json();
```

Comment: I am getting this response InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
TLS 1.2

Comment: And what does it say?

Comment: Why, with just that program, are you making an insecure request? Do you have some environment settings that are impacting your HTTP requests?

Comment: I haven't made any explicit settings. The above mentioned warning is gone after removing verify=False

Comment: Ah! Sorry, I missed the `verify=False` part :D OK, that means that this isn't the issue.

Comment: I've edited my answer, can you try calling to the Twilio API using just `requests`?

Comment: I am using requests v2.18.3 but getting the same error: requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.twilio.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /2010-04-01/Accounts/<SID>/Messages.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:600)'),))

Comment: Does twilio have limit for sending requests per trail account?

Comment: You can only send messages to numbers you have verified while you have a trial account. Otherwise I believe the API limits are the same (max of 100 concurrent requests, can only send one message per second per number).

Comment: I am certainly not exceeding the limit. Also, I am using a verified phone number. I was able to send SMS to same number few days ago

Comment: Could you send me your account SID over email at philnash@twilio.com and I'll see if something else has gone wrong with your account.

Comment: It seems like a problem with the environment. Because I faced the same error while using another trail account from my setup.

Comment: Am I missing any PEM file?

Comment: It does sound like an environment problem, however I have no further information on your environment, so it's hard to answer. You should not have a problem making calls to the Twilio API, so I would inspect the setup of your Ubuntu box and python environment.

Answer (score 0):

This is about sending request through http server, i also got this error

The answer is available on https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/TwilioBehindTheProxy

```
import os
from twilio.rest import Client
from twilio.http.http_client import TwilioHttpClient

proxy_client = TwilioHttpClient(proxy={'http': os.environ['http_proxy'], 'https': os.environ['https_proxy']})

account_sid = 'your account id here'
auth_token = 'your twilio token here'

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token, http_client=proxy_client)

# twilio api calls will now work from behind the proxy:
message = client.messages.create(to="...", from_='...', body='...')
```